# Azure CDN versioning is not showing updates

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I am trying to clear the cache of my CDN.

I have enabled query strings on my CDN endpoint to allow for fresh content.

I have updated the headers of a blob to force download rather than display in the browser. When I visit the blob directly the image downloads. If I visit it through the CDN with different version numbers at the end like **?v=2** then the headers are not present and the image does not download. Does it take time for the query string change to take effect? Or are there more steps I have missed?

Comment: You said you've "enabled query strings" - what *Query string caching behaviour* have you enabled?

Comment: In the CDN management panel I clicked "enable query string" I could only find this in the old site - manage.windowsazure.com under the CDN tab

Comment: Lots of good info in the docs - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-query-string/